# Appending string to parameters in aliased command

Tags: bash, terminal

I have a handy alias for grep defined in ~/.bashrc as follows:

```
alias gr='grep -rn "." --color=auto \
--exclude-dir={node_modules,static,venv,tests,locale} \
--exclude=\*.pyc -e $1'
```

This alias finds a certain pattern in all files except for the ones in some directories and in compiled python files:

```
kinkyboy tree
.
├── bak
│   ├── myoldfile.py
│   └── myoldfile.pyc
├── myfile.txt
└── node_modules
    └── myoldfile.txt


> gr 'hello'
./bak/myoldfile.py:1:hello there old
./myfile.txt:1:hello there
```

Say that I also want to add the bak directory to the excluded directories. How can I modify my terminal command accordingly? This will not work as it still catches the file in ./bak :

```
> gr 'hello' --exclude-dir={bak}
./bak/myoldfile.py:1:hello there old   #I wanted to exclude this folder
./myfile.txt:1:hello there
```

If I want to modify the "--exclude" parameter, this command works (it excludes both *.pyc and *.py files):

```
> gr 'hello' --exclude=\*.py
./myfile.txt:1:hello there
```

A workaround would be to pipe an exclusive grep, but then I lose the colors:

```
 gr 'hello' | grep -v '/bak/'
```

Comment: Aliases don't take parameters in `bash`, functions do! change `gr` to make it a function

Comment: @Inian Not true. I can issue the following one, for example: gr "hello" -l

Comment: They get appended as part of the command and treated as rest of the positional arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function is virtually always preferred to an alias.

```
gr () {
  # You only need to write the function once; choose readability
  grep -rn "." --color=auto \
     --exclude-dir=node_modules \
     --exclude-dir=static \
     --exclude-dir=venv \
     --exclude-dir=tests \
     --exclude-dir=locale \
     --exclude="*.pyc" \
     -e "$@"
 }
```

Your alias relies on the shell parameter `$1` being unset when you use the alias; here, `"$@"` is actually *used* to supply whatever arguments are passed to `gr` on to `grep`.

```
gr 'hello' --exclude-dir bak   # Two arguments instead of one to emphasize the use of $@
```

Answer (score 1):

**This will work**

```
gr 'hello' --exclude-dir=bak
```

**Explanation:**

> `--exclude-dir` parameter takes `table {}` only when there are multiple directories to be given, in case of a single directory without curly-braces are not used.

**Example**

```
root@114855-T480:/home/yadav22ji# gr 'hello'
./lua-5.3.5/doc/manual.html:8365:     s = "hello world from Lua"
./lua-5.3.5/doc/manual.html:8440:     x = string.gsub("hello world", "(%w+)", "%1 %1")

#Without {} 
root@114855-T480:/home/yadav22ji# gr 'hello' --exclude-dir=doc

#With {}
root@114855-T480:/home/yadav22ji# gr 'hello' --exclude-dir={doc}
./lua-5.3.5/doc/manual.html:8365:     s = "hello world from Lua"
./lua-5.3.5/doc/manual.html:8440:     x = string.gsub("hello world", "(%w+)", "%1 %1")
root@114855-T480:/home/yadav22ji# echo "hello" > onedir/samplefile
root@114855-T480:/home/yadav22ji# gr 'hello' --exclude-dir={doc}
./lua-5.3.5/doc/manual.html:8365:     s = "hello world from Lua"
./lua-5.3.5/doc/manual.html:8440:     x = string.gsub("hello world", "(%w+)", "%1 %1")
./onedir/samplefile:1:hello
root@114855-T480:/home/yadav22ji# gr 'hello' --exclude-dir=doc
./onedir/samplefile:1:hello
root@114855-T480:/home/yadav22ji# gr 'hello' --exclude-dir={doc,onedir}
root@114855-T480:/home/yadav22ji#
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are forced to use an alias, and not a function or script (I don't know why), you could change your alias to take the excluded directories from an environment variable

```
alias gr="grep -rn . --color=auto --exclude-dir={$EXCLUDEDDIRS} --exclude=\*.pyc -e $1"
```

Then you can change the value of $EXCLUDEDDIRS as you need